# Is there a practice of palming face by "shin" shape?

Tags: minhag, hands-fingers, bircas-krias-shema

A friend of mine from B7 said that there's a custom to palm one's face during Kriyat Shma with shin-shaped hand. It looks like a Cohanim's hand shape, but it forms a shin-like shape.
Who's custom is that?

Comment: What does b7 mean

Comment: @hazoriz I think it means Be'er Sheva.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen many who do this in practice, and I'm almost sure that it's always to mark the name of שד-י. The only source I could find however is [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/66689), where the rabbi who is answering the question says that Rabbi Ovadia Yosef mentions this in his book *Maor Yisrael*.

In my opinion this is much more of a *minhag* that is passed by people seeing other people and liking the gesture, but there probably are other sources of course who mention this.

Answer (score 5):

My Rosh Yeshiva, Rabbi Leib Tropper, instructed his talmidim to make a shin shape of the middle three fingers, but did not explain it. Later, a very learned chassidic/yerushalmi friend of mine told me that this, together with a folded up pinky and a 90-degree-bent thumb makes **<sub>ד</sub><sup>ש</sup><sub>י</sub>**, i.e. שדי, and I have seen many chassidim do so.